# How can i use intent in Fragment class for redirecting to another class?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-intent, fragment

In my fragment class i have some buttons so when i click that buttons i want to redirect to another Activity class. How can i use redirection in fragment class?

***fragment_services.xml***
    `

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="409dp" >
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="160dp"
    android:layout_height="90dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
    android:background="@drawable/cloud" />
 </RelativeLayout>
 </ScrollView>
 </RelativeLayout>`
```

**ServiceFragment.java**

```
public class ServiceFragment extends Fragment {
private Context CurrentObj=this;
 @Override
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) 
 {
     View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_services, container,   false);
     final Button backBtn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button3);
     backBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
     {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0)
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent redirect=new Intent(CurrentObj.getApplicationContext(),Cloud.class);
                startActivity(redirect);
            }
        });
     return rootView;
 }
```

}

***Cloud.java***

```
public class Cloud extends Activity{
private Context CurrentObj=this;
@Override

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.cloud);
}
```

}

Answer (score 4):

```
backBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
 {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent redirect=new Intent(getActivity(),Cloud.class);
            getActivity().startActivity(redirect);
        }
    });
```

You also need to make sure that your `Cloud` class is extending Activity and you have declared your `Cloud` Activity in `AndroidManifest.xml`.

I also found some little bug in your code. This line `private Context CurrentObj=this;` in `ServiceFragment` class will cause compiler error because Fragments aren't subclasses of Context or ContextWrappers. You need to change or remove this line from your Fragment.

Comment: final Button backBtn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button3);

Comment: Here am getting "The method findViewById(int) is undefined for the type ServiceFragment"

Comment: Because you should have `final Button backBtn=(Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.button3);`

Comment: Getting runtime exception " java.lang.NullPointerException" while clicking the button

Comment: @BipinD If I helped, please check my answer as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

try this `getActivity().startActivity(redirect);`

Answer (score 0):

You shouldnt forget about your parent activity.

```
Intent redirect=new Intent(getActivity(),Cloud.class);
                    getActivity().startActivity(redirect);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it using context then do as following

```
private Context CurrentObj=getActivity();

backBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
 {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent redirect=new Intent(CurrentObj,Cloud.class);
            CurrentObj.startActivity(redirect);
        }
    });
```